# How to get Transaction id when using Credit Card option in iOS PayPal SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, paypal

I got the below response when i use credit card in PayPal:

```
    {
    client =     {
        environment = sandbox;
        "paypal_sdk_version" = "1.4.3";
        platform = iOS;
        "product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";
    };
    payment =     {
        amount = "1.00";
        "currency_code" = USD;
        "short_description" = Order;
    };
    "proof_of_payment" =     {
        "rest_api" =         {
            "payment_id" = "PAY-0HB84369BG507770XKKV7ZYI";
            state = approved;
        };
    };
}
)
```

How to get the *transactionID* by using **payment_id**?

There are two steps to get the *transactionID* using PayPal REST API, 
1. Get AccessToken
2. Use AccessToken and **payment_id** to get *transactionID*.

To get the AccessToken, they given some reference code which is below, i need help to convert that code into Objective-C for last two lines, i know for headers (-H), but don't know for  -u,-d

```
    curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
  -u "EOJ2S-Z6OoN_le_KS1d75wsZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp:EClusMEUk8e9ihI7ZdVLF5cZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

I used the below code , but it is giving an error:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [theRequest addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [theRequest addValue:@"Accept-Language" forHTTPHeaderField:@"en_US"];
    [theRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSString *strClientIdAndSecretKey=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@",kPayPalClientId,kPayPalSecret];

 [theRequest setValue:strClientIdAndSecretKey forHTTPHeaderField:@"client_id:secret"];

    NSString *parameterString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"grant_type=client_credentials"];

    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [parameterString length]];

    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    //do post request for parameter passing
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[parameterString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSLog(@"Headers %@",[theRequest allHTTPHeaderFields]);

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:theRequest
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *dataOrder, NSError *error)
     {


         if(error == nil)
         {
             NSString *jsonString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataOrder encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
             NSLog(@"Result is %@",jsonString);
         }
         else
         {

         }
     }
     ];
```

Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0xabd2bf0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token, NSUnderlyingError=0xabcf950 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1012.)"}

I feel problem while passing clientid and secret, any ideas to fix this issue?

Comment: reference link: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/#get-an-access-token

Comment: Hi, I am having same issue, can you please post code how to use that URL?

Answer (score 2):

To Set credential replace this code

```
NSData * credential = [strClientIdAndSecretKey  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *credentialString = [credential base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithCarriageReturn];
[theRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@",credentialString] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

with

```
[theRequest setValue:strClientIdAndSecretKey forHTTPHeaderField:@"client_id:secret"]
```

Comment: Try this, it works for me and return a valid response

Answer (score 1):

Can you plz see the following code i hope it will be helpful to you..

**Objective-c source code:**

```
NSString *clientID = @"YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
NSString *secret = @"YOUR_SECRET";

NSString *authString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", clientID, secret];
NSData * authData = [authString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *credentials = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
[configuration setHTTPAdditionalHeaders:@{ @"Accept": @"application/json", @"Accept-Language": @"en_US", @"Content-Type": @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded", @"Authorization": credentials }];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"]];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

NSString *dataString = @"grant_type=client_credentials";
NSData *theData = [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSURLSessionUploadTask *task = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:theData completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response,   NSError *error) {
if (!error) {
    NSLog(@"data = %@", [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error]);
}
 }];

 [task resume];
```

**Response::**

```
data = {
"access_token" = "YOUR_NEW_ACCESS_TOKEN";
"app_id" = "APP-YOUR_APP_ID";
"expires_in" = 34400;
scope = "https://uri.paypal.com/services/subscriptions   https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card https://uri.paypal.com/services/applications/webhooks openid https://uri.paypal.com/services/invoicing https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.*";
"token_type" = "YOUR_Token_Type";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have these values flipped by accident:

`[theRequest addValue:@"Accept-Language" forHTTPHeaderField:@"en_US"];`

It should be:

`[theRequest addValue:@"en_US" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Language"];`